# How to convert "1324649468000" to date time format?

Tags: java, jsp

Hi I am trying to convert "1324649468000" in to date time format but my code is just giving date only ,

```
public Date Date() throws SQLException, ParseException {
   DateFormat Format; 
   String dat="1324649468000";
   Date d = new Date(Long.valueOf(dat));  
   return d;
}
```

In the jsp I am getting this method in this way,

```
<%  
try {
   out.print(inf.Date());  
} catch(IOException e) {
   out.print(e.getMessage());
}
%>
```

But I am getting just date only in this format:

```
2011-12-23
```

Comment: What format is `1324649468000` in?

Comment: @bobbymcr its unix time stamp.

Comment: @0cool actually i think it's the number of milliseconds since midnight of January 1, 1970

Answer (score 2):

No, your code *would* return a `Date` which includes the time. The class `Date` actually represents an instant in time, not just a date.

How you *use* the value returned is up to you, and you haven't shown any code for that - nor why you've declared a variable of type `DateFormat` but then not used it - but the `Date` itself is fine. (The value you've given is 2011-12-23T14:11:08Z.)

Comment: i was trying to many things for that i declare dateformat but didi not use it

Comment: @SalmanRaza: Well that would probably be due to whatever `out.print()` is doing, but the `Date` itself is fine.

Comment: @SalmanRaza, could you please use this link's code and get back to us :) http://www.jsptut.com/Directives.jsp

Comment: w8 i am trying and then let you know

Comment: @ dontCheckMyBlog i am getting date time byt his tutorial i think that i have to initialize variable of Date typr and get the return value in it at jsp side and then print it ?

Answer (score 1):

**TEST:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String dat="1324649468000";
        Date d = new Date(Long.valueOf(dat));
        System.out.println(d.toString());       
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT :** Sat Dec 24 01:11:08 EST 2011

**Works for me!**

Answer (score 1):

This will do it. Where starttime is the unixtimestamp string.

DateFormat.format("M/d/yyyy h:mma", Long.parseLong(starttime)*1000);

OUTPUT:

12/27/2011 3:14pm

Comment: i am getting time but using this code on jsp side {<HTML>
<BODY>
<%
    System.out.println( "Evaluating date now" );
    Date date = new Date();
%>
Hello!  The time is now <%= date %>
</BODY>
</HTML>} but the return value of my code is not printing it at jsp the date time while returned value has date time then waht should i add to my code ? and you have give me solution where do i use it server side or client side?

Comment: Why dont you write two functions like getTime(timestring) and getDate(timestring) and then call each as and when required.